# Attaching an uploaded file as an attachment In PHPmailer and Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, email, attachment, phpmailer

I have created a web form where people can enter registration information and upload an image to our server. I can get their name, email and message but I can't figure out how to get the uploaded file. I'd like to have the page not reload so that's why I'm using JQuery.  It mostly works but I can't get the uploaded file to be recognized in the POST data or the FILES data. The form and processor page are located in the same directory and the image get placed in a subfolder called uploads. Here is what I have so far which does not work for attaching image. I believe the problem is in the JavaScript file where I define the var photoFile = $('#submitForm #photoFile').val();  What is the correct way to declare the uploaded file?

Here's the HTML form:

```
form action="../inc/sendPhotoEmail.php" name="submitForm" id="submitForm" method="post" 
enctype="multipart/form-data">

   <label for="submitName">Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
   <input name="submitName" type="text" id="submitName" size="35" value="" />

   <label for="submitEmail">Email <span class="required">*</span></label>
   <input name="submitEmail" type="text" id="submitEmail" size="35" value="" />                       

    <label  for="submitMessage">Tell us what you want fixed <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <textarea name="submitMessage"  id="submitMessage" rows="10" cols="50" ></textarea>

    <label for="attach_photo">Attach Your Photo<span class="required"/>*</span></label>
    <input type="file" name="photoFile" id="photoFile" accept="image/*"/>

    <button class="submit" name="submitFormSubmit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
    <span id="image-loader"><img src="images/loader.gif" alt="" /></span>
</form> <!-- Form End -->

<!-- contact-warning -->
<div id="message-warning"></div>
<!-- contact-success -->
<div id="message-success">
 <i class="icon-ok"></i>Your message was sent, thank you!<br />
</div>
```

The javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

   $('form#submitForm button.submit').click(function() {

      $('#image-loader').fadeIn();

      var submitName = $('#submitForm #submitName').val();
      var submitEmail = $('#submitForm #submitEmail').val();   
      var submitMessage = $('#submitForm #submitMessage').val();
      var photoFile = $('#submitForm #photoFile').val();

      var data = 'submitName=' + submitName + '&submitEmail=' + submitEmail +
        '&submitMessage=' + submitMessage + $photoFile='+ photoFile;         

      $.ajax({

          type: "POST",
          url: "inc/sendPhotoEmail.php",
          data: data,
          success: function(msg) {

            // Message was sent
            if (msg == 'OK') {
               $('#image-loader').fadeOut();
               $('#message-warning').hide();
               $('#submitForm').fadeOut();
               $('#message-success').fadeIn();   
            }
            // There was an error
            else {
               $('#image-loader').fadeOut();
               $('#message-warning').html(msg);
                $('#message-warning').fadeIn();
            }

          }

      });

      return false;

   });
```

And the PHP file:

```
<?php

require_once('class.phpmailer.php');

$ourEmail = "repair@myemail.net";
$target_dir = "../uploads/";

if($_POST) {   

   $name = trim(stripslashes($_POST['submitName']));
   $email = trim(stripslashes($_POST['submitEmail']));
   $emailMessage = trim(stripslashes($_POST['submitMessage']));

   $image_attachment = $_POST["photoFile"]; // <---- this doesn't print anything
   $targetFile = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["photoFile"]["name"]);
   echo "targetFile = ". $targetFile . "<br/>"; // <-- this only prionts the subdirectory

   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photoFile"]["tmp_name"],$target_dir.$_FILES["photoFile"]["name"]);

   echo "Uploaded File :".$_FILES["photoFile"]["name"]. "<br/>";
   $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["photoFile"]["name"]);
   echo "target_file = ". $target_file . "<br/>";

   $mail = new PHPMailer();                    //Create a new PHPMailer instance
   $mail->isSendmail();                        // Set PHPMailer to use the sendmail transport

   // Set Message
    $mail->setFrom($email, $name);                          //Set who the message is to be sent from
    $mail->addReplyTo("replyto@example.com", "First Last"); //Set an alternative reply-to address
    $mail->addAddress($ourEmail, "Figley T. Whitesides");   //Set who the message is to be sent to
    $mail->Subject = "Repair Form Submission";              //Set the subject line
    $mail->WordWrap = 80;
    $mail->msgHTML($emailMessage);                          //Create message bodies and embed images
    $mail->addAttachment($target_file);                     //Attach an image file

    if (!$error) {
    //send the message, check for errors
        if (!$mail->send()) {
             $mail->ErrorInfo;
         } else {
             $response = "Photo sent!";
            } // end if - no validation error
    }

    else{
        $response = (isset($error['name'])) ? $error['name'] . "<br /> \n" : null;
        $response .= (isset($error['email'])) ? $error['email'] . "<br /> \n" : null;
        $response .= (isset($error['message'])) ? $error['message'] . "<br />" : null;
        $response .= (isset($error['attachment'])) ? $error['attachment'] . "<br />" : null;

        echo $response;
        } // end if - there was a validation error
}
?>


});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't upload data and files with one form using ajax, but try this code,

```
$("form#data").submit(function() {
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    $.post($(this).attr("action"), formData, function() {
        // success    
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Your suggestion worked - I can get the uploaded file name and add it as an email attachment but how do I get it on the same page?  I'd like to use the function(msg) to display success or an error.

Comment: yes you can used i also used and handle the response